# Spinner looks darker than usual

Tags: android, colors, spinner

I'm using Spinner in my android app, but I've a problem. It works fine, but its color is darker than they use to have, but I don't know why. Is not a problem with themes or styles, is more, I used Spinners recently for other project and It works perfectly. Did it happen to you? How did you solve it?

[image]

I don't use any custom component for this example, so I don't attach the code, but If you need it just ask for.

Comment: is that it appears on all devices?

Answer (score 0):

it may be because you passed different resource id to spinner arrayAdapter.. try passing android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item to your adapter

yourSpinnerArrayAdapter =new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, your_list);

hope this helps...:)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom layout for spinner, it will be more customizable

custom_spinner.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <TextView  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:gravity="left"  
    android:textColor="#000000"         
    android:padding="10dip"
    />
```

And your spinner adapter

```
  yourSpinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.custom_spinner, your_list);
```